# java - get cookie value by name in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. I have set a cookie in one of my controller's methods in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/news"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView news(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    ...
    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "test=value; Path=/");
    ...

    modelAndView.setViewName("path/to/my/view");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This is working fine and I can see a cookie with name `test` and value "value" in my browser console. Now I want to get the cookie value by name in other method. How can I get value of `test` cookie?

Comment: You should accept either meskobalazs's or ryanp's answer.

Comment: You really should accept an answer like @Frans said, it helps others with the same problems find the correct answers

Answer (score 125):

The simplest way is using it in a controller with the `@CookieValue` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@CookieValue("foo") String fooCookie) {
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can get it from the servlet request using Spring `org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils`

```
WebUtils.getCookie(HttpServletRequest request, String cookieName)
```

By the way, the code pasted into the question could be refined a bit. Instead of using `#setHeader()`, this is much more elegant:

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie("test", "value"));
```

Comment: You might want to add "required = false" on the @CookieValue annotation to avoid getting 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @evandor is there a way to catch that 400 null response and return something else. This would still be a 400, but it won't be null. Something similar to what `@GlobalExceptionHandler` does

Comment: @kerw I am working on adding a request filter for this purpose.

Comment: Also you could use `defaultValue="yourDeafultValue"` instead of `"required = false"`.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getCookie(HttpServletRequest, String)`.

Answer (score 15):

```
private String getCookieValue(HttpServletRequest req, String cookieName) {
    return Arrays.stream(req.getCookies())
            .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(cookieName))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Cookie::getValue)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: if cookies null, null exception occurred

Comment: Throw an exception instead of throwing null.
.orElseThrow(UnAuthorizedException::new)

Answer (score 6):

```
private String extractCookie(HttpServletRequest req) {
            for (Cookie c : req.getCookies()) {
               if (c.getName().equals("myCookie"))
                   return c.getValue();
               }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring MVC already gives you the `HttpServletRequest` object, it has a `getCookies()` method that returns `Cookie[]` so you can iterate on that.

Comment: Is there another way? I don't want to iterate through cookie array, because that is large array.

Comment: Even if you don't iterate over it by hand, the framework will do it for you anyway, as the cookies are stored in a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie doesnt have method to get by value try this

```
Cookie cookie[]=request.getCookies();
Cookie cook;
String uname="",pass="";
if (cookie != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
    cook = cookie[i];
    if(cook.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("loginPayrollUserName"))
            uname=cook.getValue();
    if(cook.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("loginPayrollPassword"))
            pass=cook.getValue();                   
}    
}
```