# How to delete a cookie from backend upon an error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cookies

Currently setting up http only cookie in a Spring boot project via configurations as follows.

This cookie is getting set correctly when ever I call following endpoint.

```
  @Bean
  public CookieSerializer defaultCookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer cookie = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    cookie.setDomainNamePattern(".*");
    cookie.setCookieName("my_cookie");
    cookie.setUseSecureCookie(true);
    cookie.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true);
    cookie.setCookieMaxAge(1200);
    return cookie;
  }
```

As can see, the cookie called `my_cookie` is being set for 2 mins.

In my controller within same project, I have the following controller method.

In the event I enter the error block, I wish to delete the cookie called `my_cookie`. How can I do that?

This is the closest question I found for this but is not the same case considering I set it via configurations.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821919/delete-cookie-from-a-servlet-response

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
  public List CustomResponse(
          @RequestBody Request request,
  ) throws Exception {

    CustomResponse response = null;
    if (otherCookie != null) {
        CustomResponse response = // perform some other rest request and get value from there 
    }

    if (response == null) {

        // I want to delete the cookie named `my_cookie` at this stage. 

        throw new CustomException('name');
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118342/java-get-cookie-value-by-name-in-spring-mvc.

Comment: [This](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-cookies-in-spring-boot) article by Atta Shah provides another way to set, retrieve, and delete cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a cookie, set the Max-Age directive to 0 and unset its value. You must also pass the same other cookie properties you used to set it. Don't set the Max-Age directive value to -1. Otherwise, it will be treated as a session cookie by the browser.

```
// create a cookie
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("username", null);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setPath("/");

//add cookie to response
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

For more, refer to the post by Dzone:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-cookies-in-spring-boot