# <Spring Boot> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am starting to lose my mind here. My project is ran on Spring boot and React, I am trying to implement a logout functionality. I want to make this work:

1. User is logged in
2. User clicks on Log out
3. The JWT token cookie gets deleted, user gets redirected to localhost:3000

From react app (localhost:3000), i want to call the "/exit" endpoint on Spring Boot server (localhost:8080/exit). There are no other issues with cors apart from this with my implementation (no errors when fetching data from the server, logging in or registering a user).

Here is the code (Spring Boot):

(UserController.java)

```
    @RequestMapping("/exit")
    public void exit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // token can be revoked here if needed
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, null, null);
        try {
            //sending back to client app
            response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
            System.out.println("called logout endpoint");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(SecurityConfig.java)

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**", "/register/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/student/**").hasAuthority(Role.STUDENT.getCode());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/teacher/**").hasAuthority(Role.TEACHER.getCode());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/coordinator/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.COORDINATOR.getCode(), Role.ADMIN.getCode());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.getCode());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/exit").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/exit")
                .deleteCookies("access_token")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000");
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), jwtAlgorithm(), userRepository));
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(userDetailsService, jwtAlgorithm()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

(SecurityConfig.java)

```
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000/", "http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

All I want is to get rid of the damn

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' (redirected from
> 'http://localhost:8080/exit') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
> is present on the requested resource.

error. Without essentially turning the cors completely off.

I've looked over most posts here asking similar questions, I haven't found the answer. Nothing worked yet. The error remains the same.

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be related to `response.sendRedirect` line. With this command, it is as if you have sent a request to the client side, from the server side. So the `CORS policy` comes into play again. I have no experience with React, but I think you need to configure the WebServer on which the React application is running. Or, instead of sendRedirect, you can return `200 OK` and do this redirect on the client side.

Comment: Thank you, it's very nice to at least know from which side the wind blows, because until now I had no clue what needs to be looked into deeper. This solution should work, hopefully. I'll get back to you if it doesn't!

Comment: Your suggestion worked, however a new problem arose. If I send the request through browser (localhost:8080/exit), it works. It signs the user out, however, it also redirects him to localhost:8080/login?logout. There's no piece of code in my implementation that does this. Have any suggestion on how to debug this?

Comment: It has to be related to settings you made in SecurityConfig.java. By the way, SpringSecurity will redirect user after logout because of your configuration. http
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/exit")
                .deleteCookies("access_token")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000");

Comment: @Pehy Is it solved? Was the answer useful for you?

Comment: Sadly not everything is resolved. I was unable to get the JWT token (which is in cookies) removed on backend. I've tried the implicit Spring Security logout endpoint, as well as custom endpoints calling SecurityContextHolder to invalidate the token server-side. I was able to fix the redirects however. For now, I am only deleting the token from cookies client-side. I had to make the cookie holding the token non-httponly though, as I don't see a solution at the moment with my implementation.

Comment: @Pehy You can also remove cookie from backend if you want. See related discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214936/how-to-delete-a-cookie-from-backend-upon-an-error